# Cordova black berry 10 compile issue (Package-Author-Id)

Tags: cordova, build, blackberry-10

I'm unable to compile blackberry version of my app with cordova.

Command : `cordova build blackberry10 --verbose`

Output :

```
Running command: /home/MyUser/dev/git/cmaApp/platforms/blackberry10/cordova/build 
[INFO]    Populating application source
[INFO]    Parsing config.xml
[INFO]    Generating output files
[WARN]    Failed to find debug token. If you have an existing debug token, please copy it to /home/MyUser/.cordova/blackberry10debugtoken.bar. To generate a new debug token, execute the 'run' command.
[INFO]    Warning: Cannot find application or default icon
[INFO]    Package created: /home/MyUser/dev/git/cmaApp/platforms/blackberry10/build/simulator/bb10app.bar
[ERROR]   MANIFEST.MF: Invalid value 'testTCfDqXF1aXBlIEZvcmdlIFpv' for attribute 'Package-Author-Id'.
[ERROR]   Native Packager exception occurred
[WARN]    Failed to find debug token. If you have an existing debug token, please copy it to /home/MyUser/.cordova/blackberry10debugtoken.bar. To generate a new debug token, execute the 'run' command.
[INFO]    Warning: Cannot find application or default icon
[INFO]    Package created: /home/MyUser/dev/git/cmaApp/platforms/blackberry10/build/device/bb10app.bar
[ERROR]   MANIFEST.MF: Invalid value 'testTCfDqXF1aXBlIEZvcmdlIFpv' for attribute 'Package-Author-Id'.
[ERROR]   Native Packager exception occurred
An error has occurred
Command finished with error code 2: /home/MyUser/dev/git/cmaApp/platforms/blackberry10/cordova/build 
Error: /home/MyUser/dev/git/cmaApp/platforms/blackberry10/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/home/MyUser/app/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:135:23)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:735:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:802:5)
```

Black Berry part in config.xml :

```
<platform name="blackberry10">
    <rim:permissions>
        <rim:permit system="true">_sys_use_consumer_push</rim:permit>
        <rim:permit>access_location_services</rim:permit>
        <rim:permit>bbm_connect</rim:permit>
        <rim:permit>post_notifications</rim:permit>
        <rim:permit>read_device_identifying_information</rim:permit>
        <rim:permit>access_shared</rim:permit>
        <rim:permit>run_when_backgrounded</rim:permit>
    </rim:permissions>
    <feature id="blackberry.system" required="true" version="1.0.0.0" />
    <feature id="org.apache.cordova" required="true" version="1.0.0" />
    <feature id="blackberry.app" required="true" version="1.0.0.0" />
    <feature id="blackberry.app.event" required="true" version="1.0.0.0" />
    <feature id="blackberry.system.event" required="true" version="1.0.0.0"/>
    <access subdomains="false" uri="http://mywebsite.com"/>
</platform>
```

While searching, I found that "Package-Author-Id" must be in lowercase but I don't know where `testTCfDqXF1aXBlIEZvcmdlIFpv` string come from (I searched in project app, ~/.cordova, sdk folder).
I searched for `MANIFEST.MF` file but i did not find it, I guess it is generated in cordova build process.

How can i modify `Package-Author-Id` or build my app ?

Cordova : 3.6.3-0.2.13
Black berry webworks sdk : 2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Package-Author-Id` case is not the problem, this string seems to be generated with `author` string from config.xml.
I did not find how to change it, but black berry does not accept accent in `author` (at least with cordova 3.6.3) in config.xml file.
I just replace accent and all works fine.